# Img tag getting removed in views drupal 8

Tags: views

I am trying to rewrite the results of a field to include an img tag.
The first part of the tag then gets stripped, the second part stays:

```
<img src="http://example.com alt="Image" /> results in alt="Image" />.
```

What is causing it and what will be work around for it.

Answer (score 0):

I was using wrong image formatter . Instead of rendering the image the image tag was being rendered.